# In Typescript how do you type for (const element of elements ) {}

Tags: typescript

I tried

```
for (const element as ElementType of elements ) {}
```

or

```
for (const element of elements as ElementType) {}
```

Both are incorrect.

Comment: I assume you have to do this because the type of the array is undefined/unknown? If yes, I would recommend using user-defined type guards, [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: I just looked at your profile and it seems you are mainly doing c#? You don't need to specify the type of the variable. Let's say the array is of type `string[]`, the constant automatically becomes the singular of the array type (in this case `string`).

Comment: @Elias thanks will think about that, had switched to something else will have to come back later :)

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to do anything.

```
interface TestElement {
    id: Number;
}

const arr: TestElement[] = [];

for (const element of arr ) {
    element // It is implicitly cast to TestElement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why Typescript doesn't allow type annotations or type assertions on variables like this in `for`/`of` loops. You can achieve something similar by asserting the type of the array, rather than the element:

```
let arr: any = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (let x of (arr as number[])) {
    x // number
}
```

It's a bit messy because of the extra brackets, but it does the job.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjBc0B2BPCBeCBtAjAGggCYCBmAgFgF0BuAKFoDMB7GCAClEgA8ImH3YrKAGcISAK4BbAEYgYWSgEpFEAN60ImiDwD0OsVNkxaAX1pA)

Comment: They probably do not allow this because if you run into this issue, something else is not quite right with the code. Nothing should really be declared as `any`.

Comment: "Nothing should be `any`" is a very rigid, idealistic opinion. Typescript's type system is very powerful but no type system can prove every provable property of all code; and even the language's own "strict mode" only warns about *implicit* `any`, with no rule against explicit `any` types. So the language is certainly not designed to always discourage you from using `any`. Still, the same thing can be needed in other situations, e.g. the union type `number[] | undefined` where the programmer knows that the array exists but the compiler can't prove it.

Comment: The latter I often do use. You can eliminate the undefined by a simple if statement. If you use eslint-typescript, "no any" is a recommended rule and I'm totally behind it. You could also just write normal javascript instead. It's like stating eliminating 80% of the bugs is enough. But I also get why you are saying it... sometimes it is really convenient to just go: "Yeah, don't worry about it".

Comment: Yes, you could write an `if` statement, but sometimes it is provable that `arr` cannot be undefined at that point in the code, so the `if` statement's condition would always be true and would just be there to convince the compiler that it's not a type error. In that case, a type assertion does the same thing in a way which makes more sense to humans reading the code; an `if` statement might misleadingly suggest to the reader that the condition is possibly false.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree :P